# Convert string to Font

Tags: c#, winforms, string, fonts, parsing

I've been having a hard time trying to get the right answers for my problem. And have spent numerous days searching online and in documentation and have found nothing.

I have a Text File that contains a bunch of text. And on one of those lines inside the file will contain some Font info like this:

Tahoma,12.5,Regular

Note that the font info will not always have the same font name, size or style so I can't just set it manually.

When this file is opened into my app, it will parse the contents (which I have mostly covered), I just need some help converting the above font string into an actual font object and then assigning that font to a control, i.e.  a label etc...

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: why create a duplicate question?

Comment: i was advised to. and the second question i created resulted in worse answers than the first time.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the [Font class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx). Assuming you use String.Split() to parse the text into an array you will want to take each part of the array and use it to [create a Font object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.font.aspx) like:

```
string s = "Tahoma,12.5,Regular";
string[] fi = s.Split(',');
Font font = new Font(fi[0], fi[1],fi[2]);
```

I don't have a C# compiler on this Mac so it may not be exactly correct.

Example constructor:

```
public Font(
string familyName,
float emSize,
FontStyle style
)
```

Here you need to specify the second argument as a float, so cast the string to a float with:

```
(float)fi[1]
```

Next you need to lookup a FontStyle based on what fi[2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.font.aspx) is:

```
   if (fi[2] == "Regular") {
      // set font style
   }
```

Comment: thank you brianly - i have 2 errors though i'm not too sure what they mean exactly. the first one says:

Argument '2': cannot convert from 'string' to 'float' ..and the second says:

Argument '3': cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Drawing.FontStyle'..

Comment: You need to look at the docs I linked to for the Font constructors. My example has too many arguments. Find a constructor that matches the arguments you want to pass in.

Comment: Thank you BrianLy, I really appreciate you helping me. I'm still having the same problem but feel that I am getting closer to what I'm trying to acheive. +1

Comment: This approach will work for the font name and size, but the font constructor doesn't accept strings for the fontstyle. turns out its an enumeration. I found a solution that might work here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529259/return-fontstyle-from-string-name