# Return FontStyle from string name

Tags: c#, parsing, fonts

I want to write a function which will return FontStyle and take string as Parameter

```
FontStyle f = function ("Italic"); // FontStyles.Italic
```

I don't want to write Switch case or if else statements to do the same.

Can it be done for case insensitive strings?

```
FontStyle f = function ("italic");
FontStyle f = function ("itAlic");
```

should return same.

Comment: @MichalPowaga why did you add "In `namespace System.Windows`"?

Comment: @Default weird, I'm almost sure that it was there before I've formatted it... but revisions doesn't show so (is it possible in SO). I wouldn't change question in such a manner (different meaning). ps. I even didn't spot it, that's why I've written about `System.Drawing.FontStyle` in Damien_The_Unbeliever answer.

Comment: @MichałPowaga it seems you were right though. could it be some kind of merge between OP's edit and yours perhaps? Maybe you just knew he was talking about the `System.Windows` namespace and added it subconsciously :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use reflection for this:

```
var propertyInfo = typeof(FontStyles).GetProperty("Italic",
                                                  BindingFlags.Static |
                                                  BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
FontStyle f = (FontStyle)propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks. its working fine. Can it be modified to get Fontstyle with case insensitive string . eg. for "Italic" or "italic" or "ItaLic"

Comment: @user270014: Yes. Just add another binding flag: [`BindingFlags.IgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

In C# it is just an enumeration. So you can convert it like this:

```
FontStyle f = (FontStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(FontStyle), "Italic", true);
```